# How to import 3d objects in unity at run time in android application?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

We are looking for a solution that allows 3d objects to be downloaded from server at run time in unity.

Comment: As the solution below states you need to pack them as `AssetBundles` first. Runtime import of `fbx` or `obj` files is only possible if you somehow manage to build a runtime version of the asset `BuildPipeline`, because it is only available in the Editor namespace. There is a plugin on the asset store that does that if I'm not mistaken but you can just use `AssetBundles` to compile your packs and load them that way.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Put all the 3d objects in a folder and put that folder under Assets. BuildPipeline
is a class which is used to add the features at teh runtime of the android application .

### You Tube Link

[Add object at run objects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEoEvDYNa1w)

### Note

Please follow the instructions carefully and put all the 3d objects under the Assets folder because all the assets which works in the run time always pick from the folder under Assets folder as there is a proper hierarchical structure followed by the unity.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

    public class BuildAssetBundlesExample : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [MenuItem("Example/Build Asset Bundles")]
        static void BuildABs()
        {
            // Put the bundles in a folder called "ABs" within the Assets folder.
            BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles("Assets/ABs", BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wrote a little custom editor window helper script if you are interested. 
Can be found here [AssetBundleCreatorWindow.cs](https://gist.github.com/TehMightyPotato/a85e6c5648184fefe4474ac6621657f2)

Comment: TehMightyPotato good work bro . Kindly like my answer if you see it helpful